# Help in Understanding the Proof of Baire-Category theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-writing

In the proof of the Baire category theorem(for non-empty Banach Spaces), I cannot understand the following

**Baire Category Theorem: A non-empty Banach Space cannot be a countable union of nowhere dense sets**

The proof is trying to show by contradiction that a Banach space $X$ cannot be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets(rare sets).
The proof begins by assuming that suppose $\exists$ a sequence $ (A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of nowhere dense sets such that 
$$X=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$$
The proof says let $x_1 \notin A_1$ and $B_{r_1}(x_1)$ be a ball such that $B_{r_1}(x_1)\cap \overline{A_1}={\phi}$ and $r_1<1$

I am stuck on the first step. Why can we choose such a $r_1$ and why does such an open ball exist. 
Does a non-empty Banach space always contain an open set ? Could someone explain the fist part of the proof?

Comment: $A_1$ is nowhere dense. Hence $\overline{A_1}$ has emtpy interior. In particular, $X\setminus \overline{A_1} \neq \varnothing$, since $\overset{\Large\circ}{X} = X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean by the dot over $X$? I havent seen this notation

Comment: It means the interior, dual to how $\overline A$ means closure.

Comment: The interior of a set. Is $\operatorname{int} X$ the notation you know?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes I know it as $Int(\overline{A)}$

Comment: @DanielFischer I am a bit confused. Why can't $X=\overline{A_1}$? I mean the reason you give i.e $int (X)=X \implies X $is open but X is Banach space which is closed by definition?

Comment: In every topological space $T$, the set $T$ is both, open and closed. So in a non-empty topological space, a nowhere dense set is never dense in the whole space, for the whole space has non-empty interior (the whole space).